# How to plot a 3d graph in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, 3d

I'm trying to plot a 3d graph in python. But I am getting an error:could not convert string to float 2019-04-18
This error is shown on only one particular date i.e. 2019-04-18.
Help me out.
PS - I'm new to coding

```
from typing import List
import datetime as dt
from datetime import date
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
X = input("Enter ticker name")

start = dt.datetime(2017, 1, 1)
end = date.today()
df = web.DataReader(X, 'yahoo', start, end)

dates: List[str] = []
for x in range(len(df)):
    new_date = str(df.index[x])
    new_date = new_date[0:10]
    dates.append(new_date)

close = df['Close']
high = df['High']
low = df['Low']
volume = df['Volume']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(dates, volume, close, c='r', marker='o')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('high')
ax.set_zlabel('Close')
plt.show()


error =  File "C:\Users\shrey\PycharmProject\Buysellhold\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2019-04-18'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using scatter with 3D axes you need to provide the Cartesian x,y-coordinates. Therefore you need to translate the strings used for the x-coordinates to numerical values. One way would be to use the number of days between each date in the list of dates and some reference date (e.g. the earliest date in the list) and reset the xtick labels afterwards, e.g.

```
min_date = min(df.index)
days = [(dd-min_date).days for dd in df.index]
ax.scatter(days, volume, close, c='r', marker='o')
labels = ((min_date + pd.Timedelta(dd, unit='D')).date() for dd in ax.get_xticks())
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```